# Magento 2: Create new customer attribute in module upgrade

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes

I want to add new customer attribute **'business_type'** which would be a **selectbox**.

I want to do it in already created module, so I would need module update script.

Can anyone help me on this as I am new to Magento2.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how much time will it take to get a solution?

Comment: want this attribute on admin site ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Update module setup version in module.xml file. like setup_version="1.1.0"
2) Create file **CustomerSetup.php** into **Setup/** directory.

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.0') < 0){

                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customerSetup = $objectManager->create('Vendor\ModuleName\Setup\CustomerSetup');
                $customerSetup->installAttributes($customerSetup);



         }
    }
}
```

3) Create file UpgradeData.php into Setup/ folder.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Context $context,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
        ) {
        $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);
    } 

    public function installAttributes($customerSetup) {
        $this -> installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup);
        $this -> installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup);
    } 

    public function installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup) {


        $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'business_type',
            [
            'label' => 'Business Type',
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 100,
            'sort_order' =>100,
            'visible' =>  true,
            'note' => '',


                        'type' => 'int',
                        'input' => 'select',
                        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                        'option' =>
                        array (
                            'values' =>
                                array (
                                    0 => 'Option1',
                                    1 => 'Option2',
                                    2 => 'Option3',
                                ),
                        ),

            ]
            );

        $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'business_type')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout']) -> save();


    } 

    public function installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup) {

    } 

    public function getEavConfig() {
        return $this -> eavConfig;
    } 
}
```

After that Run Command . I hope it's working for you

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

namespace Test\Customer\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

/**
 * Upgrade Data Class
 *
 * @package   Test\Customer
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Attribute Set Factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * Customer Setup Factory
     *
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;


    /**
     * Upgrade Data Class Constructor.
     *
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory Customer Setup Factory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory  $attributeSetFactory  Attribute Set Factory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory  = $attributeSetFactory;
    }//end __construct()


    /**
     * Upgrade Script to create custom customer attributes
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup   Module Data Setup Interface
     * @param ModuleContextInterface   $context Module Context Interface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.0', '<')) {
            $this->createDropdownAttribute($setup);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }//end upgrade()


    /**
     * create country_code customer attribute
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup Setup
     */
    private function createDropdownAttribute($setup) : void
    {
        $attributeCode  = 'dropdown_attribute';
        $attributeLabel = 'Dropdown Attribute';

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet     = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, [
            'label' => $attributeLabel,
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'Test\Customer\Model\Source\DropdownValues',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'position' => 95,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode)
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => [
                    'customer_account_edit',
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                ],
                'is_used_for_customer_segment' => false,
                'is_system' => 0,
                'is_user_defined' => 1,
                'is_visible' => 1,
            ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }//end createDropdownAttribute()


}//end class
```

```
<?php

namespace Test\Customer\Model\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table as SourceTable;

/**
 * Class DropdownValues
 * @package Test\Customer\Model\Source
 */
class DropdownValues extends SourceTable
{


    /**
     * Retrieve Full Option values array
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions() : array
    {
        $this->_options = $this->getDropDownOptions();

        return $this->_options;
    }//end getAllOptions()


    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDropDownOptions(): array
    {
        return [
            [
                'label' => 'First Value',
                'value' => 'First Value',
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Second Value',
                'value' => 'Second Value',
            ],
            // You can add as much as you want.
        ];
    }//end getDropDownOptions()


}//end class
```

This might help you to create dropdown attribute.

Comment: Thanks mate, thanks for your time :)

Comment: I am having similar issue how can solve this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313962/eav-attribute-option-and-eav-attribute-option-value-not-getting-updated-after-ad